# call function in lua from different lua class

Tags: function, lua

I have a function

```
function f1(msg) return value end
```

in Lua file A.lua, how i can call this function or the return result of this function from a B.lua
Thank you 
Jp

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the require function ( http://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html )

```
require("A")
f1("my message")
```

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to [brianm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499395/brianm), you can also

```
dofile("A.lua")
f1("blah")
```

or

```
local chunk = assert(loadfile("A.lua"))
chunk()
f1("blah")
```

Comment: Since `require` must be without the `.lua` extension, it isn't possible to load lua files with other extension than `.lua`. The `dofile` solution works for any lua file extension.